ubuntu 22 in Vmware , cyclictest has very bad results
I am having difficulty with Ubuntu in a VMware environment and need some expert eyes on this to identify what could be wrong or what changes need to be made in VMware or the guest OS. I tested the same setup with a low-latency kernel as well.
vbnet
Copy code
#/dev/cpu_dma_latency set to 0us
WARN: reported clock resolution: 1 nsec
WARN: measured clock resolution approximately: 25 nsec
policy: fifo: loadavg: 0.57 0.21 0.13 1/535 923887
T: 0 (923834) P:99 I:1000 C: 16028 Min: 11 Act: 11 Avg: 235 Max: 2089577

Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. As written, your question is off-topic here. In any case, it lacks a question (!), lots of context, including steps to reproduce it ([mcve]) and the expected results.
